# Itextsharp dll version error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dll, itext

I am using `itextsharp` in my application for generating pdf and it was working fine.But in the last couple of days I am getting the following error

```
 "Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.9.0,  
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or one of its
  dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match
  the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

I checked the dll in the bin folder and am sure that the dll version is `5.5.8.0` and the webconfig looks like this

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.8.0" newVersion="5.5.8.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp.xmlworker" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.8.0" newVersion="5.5.8.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Is it hosting related issue or is it issue from our side ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like dll reference is being updated, but not the web.config. Try updating your web.config to version 5.5.9.0 as below.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.8.0" newVersion="5.5.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp.xmlworker" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.8.0" newVersion="5.5.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```